# Building a groovy project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I have imported a groovy project in my eclipse and I have installed the groovy plugins in my eclipse too. now, I want to build my project(which is a groovy-gradle plugin) in eclipse and use it further. I have gone through a link http://www.selikoff.net/2013/01/11/creating-a-groovy-project-with-gradle-in-eclipse/ but I don't understand how to build my project. I don't get build option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the gradle  plugins.
Some tasks will be available in the tasks Window.
Right click on build task and run it.